# Managing text files Android

Tags: android

I've got a little problem while managing .txt files on Android. I've found this [link](http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/?p=2019) (it's in Spanish) that explains how to use text files on my Android device.

What I want to do, is create a text file using the intern memory of the device, as I don't want the user depend on a SD card, and a raw text file won't allow me to write on in, only read. So I want a text file that can append some information and, in a particular case, delete all the content in the text file and reset it.

I've written this code for the writing side:

```
OutputStreamWriter fout = null;
try
{
    fout = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("measures.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND));
    fout.write(measure);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.e("Files", "Error while opening to write file measures.txt");
}
finally
{
try 
{
    fout.close();
}
catch (IOException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

I guess this part opens the file "measure.txt" in the APPEND mode, or creates it in APPEND mode.

When I try to read from it:

```
BufferedReader fin = null;
try
{
    fin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(context.openFileInput("medidas.txt")));
String line = fin.readLine();
// Some staff with this line
fin.close()
}
// catch staff
```

What I want to do is delete all the content in the text file before I close the file. The idea is store the information in another type of variable, and then, when I finish reading from file, reset the content.

How can I do that?

Comment: What happens when you try to read? i mean,do you get any exception or so?

Comment: There are many examples online on how to write to a file in internal memory & append to a file. What is the problem you face? Just google it, you will find.

Comment: I've googled it. When I read, I don't have any exception. It reads correclty. The thing is, when I finish managing the information, I want to erase all the content on the text file, but I couldn't find any information of this. :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved my problem doing this:

```
deleteFile("measures.txt");
```

And that will [i]erase[/i] for sure the file... :P